# Execute function only once after multiple clicks in a row JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have two quantity selector buttons.

After the user clicks in any of these buttons (increasing or decreasing quantity), I need to run a function.

But the user can click several times in a row, and I want to execute the function only once.

Like, wait 1 second after each click to run the function. If within this 1 second the user clicks the button again, reset the timer and wait for another second to run the function. When the user doesn´t click again within 1 second, run the function.

What´s the best way to do that in vanilla javascript?

Comment: I would copy https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/debounce.js into the codebase

Comment: When user clicked legally, set a variable as false and set a timeout to some seconds later till click becomes legal , in timeout function set the var to true. when the var is false other clicks are illegal and should be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You described a classic `debounce` technique. Here is an implementation:

Taken from https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore#_debounce

Another way is to dig into Lodash source codes and copy it from there

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    }, wait);
    if (immediate && !timeout) func.apply(context, args);
  };
}

// Avoid costly calculations while the window size is in flux.
jQuery(window).on('resize', debounce(calculateLayout, 150));
```

Here is a nice article and a playground about it https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

Answer (score 3):

You just need to start a 1 second timer and reset it whenever the button click happens.

```js
let timer

function handleClick() {
  clearTimeout(timer)
  timer = setTimeout(doSomething, 1000);
}

function doSomething() {
  let div = document.getElementById("list")
  let p = document.createElement("p")
  p.textContent = "1 second passed without a click"
  div.append(p)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button onclick="handleClick()">Click me</button>
  <div id=list></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two solutions:

1. If each click triggers some request, then disable button until the request is completed
2. Use throttling for the function invoke. You can use RxJS's throttle or you can write your own throttle method.

https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/debouncing-throttling-in-javascript-d36ace200cea

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in Vanilla JS :

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

const callback = event => {
 console.log(event);
 clearInterval(interval);
}

let interval;

btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
 clearInterval(interval);
 interval = setInterval( () => callback(event), 1000);
});
```

And the HTML :

```
<html>
<body>
 <button id="btn">test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

That way you can pass the event instance to your callback.